# Eclipse: how to prevent formatting multi-line concatenated strings?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm having this issue with Eclipse where I'm writing a JPQL query and eclipse keeps formatting the concatenations onto the same line. For example, this is what I want:

```
@Query(
      "SELECT p "
          + "FROM Person p "
          + "LEFT JOIN FETCH p.Address a "
          + "WHERE p.id = :personId "
          + "ORDER BY p.id DESC")
  public List<Person> findPerson(@Param("personId") Long personId);
```

However, Eclipse keeps changing the query to this:

```
@Query(
      "SELECT p "
          + "FROM Person p " + "LEFT JOIN FETCH p.Address a " + "WHERE p.id = :personId "
          + "ORDER BY p.id DESC")
```

Does anyone know how to prevent this? I'm using Java 11 so text blocks aren't an option here

Comment: There is an open bug about this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=425473. One comment on this is `You can disable joining already formatted lines (Code Style > Formatter > Edit > Line Wrapping tab)`.

Comment: If nothing else, try a `//` comment at the end of the line.

Comment: @ChristianBaumann Thanks! That seemed to do the trick for me

Answer (score 2):

There is an open bug about this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=425473

One comment on this is

> You can disable joining already formatted lines (`Code Style > Formatter > Edit > Line Wrapping tab`)

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of the following.

```
public class QueryFormat {
    // Add padding in line end
    // Good: No need to edit formatting profile
    // Bad: Decrease readability and need to do manual work.
    @Query("SELECT p " /*                                        */
            + "FROM Person p " /*                                        */
            + "LEFT JOIN FETCH p.Address a " /*                                        */
            + "WHERE p.id = :personId " /*                                        */
            + "ORDER BY p.id DESC")
    public List<Person> findPerson1(@Param("personId") Long personId) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    // Need to enable "Off/On Tags" -> check "Enable Off/On Tags"
    // Good: Will not affect existing formatting
    // Bad: Need to format space, indentation yourself
    // @formatter:off
    @Query("SELECT p " 
            + "FROM Person p " 
            + "LEFT JOIN FETCH p.Address a " 
            + "WHERE p.id = :personId " 
            + "ORDER BY p.id DESC")
    // @formatter:on
    public List<Person> findPerson2(@Param("personId") Long personId) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    // Code Style > Formatter > Edit > Line Wrapping tab > Check "Never Join already
    // wrapped line (suggested by Christian Baumann)"
    // Good: Seems to be best out of three, preserve formatting while line will not be
    // joined
    // Bad: May change existing formatting
    @Query("SELECT p "
            + "FROM Person p "
            + "LEFT JOIN FETCH p.Address a "
            + "WHERE p.id = :personId "
            + "ORDER BY p.id DESC")
    public List<Person> findPerson3(@Param("personId") Long personId) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just

1. edit a non-built-in profile or add a new one.
2. enable Off/On tags [image: Off/On tags]
3. be aware: there is no space after the colon ***@formatter:on/off***